# R: box plot still displaying extra space for removed rows

Tags: r, boxplot

If you take this dataframe:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
```

And you remove a row based on a specific string value by:

```
newDf <- employ.data[employ.data$employee == "John Doe",]
```

And create a boxplot:

```
boxplot(newDf$salary ~ newDf$employee)
```

Then your boxplot looks like this:

[image: boxplot]

Why does it also give extra space for removed data and does it look ugly therefore? How to solve this issue?

Comment: read the dataframe as strings `employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large y axis empty space is just a feature, you should have more y values then the plot will be OK. As for the removed categories use `newDf <- droplevels(employ.data[employ.data$employee == "John Doe",])`.

Comment: Thank you @user2974951. If I use droplevels then it works much better! :)